# Runtime exception during retrieval of object

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    List a =new ArrayList<Object>();
    a.add("asha");
    a.add("saha");
    ArrayList<SampleObject> sampleObjects =(ArrayList<SampleObject>)a;//Yes this should not be done but still
    sampleObjects.get(0).getName();// exception is thrown here

}
```

And the class is

```
  public class SampleObject implements Serializable
{
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    private String name;
    private  String number;
}
```

Can someone please explain why is this runtime exception. 
How was the data inserted in sampleObjects when the types itself doesnot match?

Comment: What exception exactly do you see?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* this throw an exception?  What do you expect `getName()` to return for a string?

Comment: i think it's a cast exception , not related to `getName()` it's this line `sampleObjects =(ArrayList<SampleObject>)a;` not the one you say it is, worst case (it's not this case) `getName()` will return null, this should not be a problem. only possible exception i see in this line `sampleObjects.get(0).getName();` is Out of range exception, i.e sampleObjects is empty.

Comment: its more of understanding here than my expectation. The exception i get is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String. Here i am trying to know the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a cast, you're assuming the responsibility for the object you cast (on this case String) to be of the type you're casting to (on this case SampleObject). Later, at runtime, the JVM discovers you didn't fulfill that responsibility (a String is not a SampleObject) and complains with a RuntimeException (more precisely a ClassCastException).

Comment: Your cast introduces [heap pollution](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ050)

Answer (score 0):

The exception says you cannot cast String objects to SampleObject type. For a proper retrieval of name properties try this;

```
SampleObject s1 = new SampleObject();
    s1.setName("asha");
    SampleObject s2 = new SampleObject();
    s1.setName("saha");

    ArrayList<SampleObject> sampleObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    sampleObjects.add(s1);
    sampleObjects.add(s2);

    System.out.println(sampleObjects.get(0).getName());
```